# Sympy "wrongly" solving system of ODEs

Tags: python, sympy

I have two ODEs that I define in sympy as follows:

```py
import sympy as sp

a = sp.Symbol("a", positive=True)
b = sp.Symbol("b", positive=True)
t = sp.Symbol("t")
x = sp.Function("x")
y = sp.Function("y")

eq = (
    sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(x(t), t), -a * x(t)),
    sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(y(t), t), a * x(t) - b * y(t)),
)
```

When I try to solve them using `dsolve` I get the following results:

```py
>>> sp.dsolve(eq)

[Eq(x(t), -C1*(a - b)*exp(-a*t)/a),
 Eq(y(t), C1*exp(-a*t) + C2*exp(-b*t))]
```

When solving the first equation alone I get the following:

```py
>>> sp.dsolve(eq[0])

Eq(x(t), C1*exp(-a*t))
```

How is it possible that the first ODE not dependent on the second ODE in `y(t)` suddenly contains `b`? Solving it with mathematica seems to give the correct result:

```
x(t) = C1*exp(-at)
y(t) = C2*exp(-bt) - (a*exp(-at-bt)*(-exp(at)+exp(bt))*C1)/(a-b)
```

Any help in solving this with python would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from SymPy is correct. It is also equivalent to the one from Mathematica just with a different definition of the arbitrary constants. You can substitute something like `C1 -> -C1*(a/(a-b))` to convert from one form to another:

```
In [49]: sp.dsolve(eq)
Out[49]: 
⎡                    -a⋅t                             ⎤
⎢       -C₁⋅(a - b)⋅ℯ                  -a⋅t       -b⋅t⎥
⎢x(t) = ──────────────────, y(t) = C₁⋅ℯ     + C₂⋅ℯ    ⎥
⎣               a                                     ⎦
```

You can also get a slightly different form if you vary the order of the functions to be solved for:

```
In [53]: sp.dsolve(eq, [y(t), x(t)])
Out[53]: 
⎡               -a⋅t                            ⎤
⎢         C₁⋅a⋅ℯ           -b⋅t             -a⋅t⎥
⎢y(t) = - ────────── + C₂⋅ℯ    , x(t) = C₁⋅ℯ    ⎥
⎣           a - b                               ⎦
```

In each equation separately the coefficient of `exp(-a*t)` can be an arbitrary constant. Usually other parameters like `a` and `b` can be absorbed into an arbitrary constant to simplify the result. However there is a constraint between the coefficients in the solutions for x and y so that the coefficient for one has to be different from the coefficient in the other equation by a factor of `-a/(a-b)`. Here SymPy chooses to absorb the parameters in the last equation but that means they have to reappear in the first.

You can see the same factor in the output you showed from Mathematica:

```
⎡                               ⎛   a⋅t    b⋅t⎞  -a⋅t - b⋅t           ⎤
⎢           -a⋅t           C₁⋅a⋅⎝- ℯ    + ℯ   ⎠⋅ℯ                 -b⋅t⎥
⎢x(t) = C₁⋅ℯ    , y(t) = - ──────────────────────────────── + C₂⋅ℯ    ⎥
⎣                                       a - b                         ⎦
```

All of these are valid general solutions for the original ODEs but differ in exactly how the arbitrary constants are defined so it's just a matter of taste which you prefer.

Personally I like the Mathematica output the least because it mixes the coefficients for the two exponential terms. I can understand where it comes from though because it's basically the raw output from the matrix exponential:

```
In [60]: M = sp.Matrix([[-a, 0], [a, -b]])

In [60]: (M*t).exp().applyfunc(sp.factor) * sp.Matrix([C1, C2])
Out[60]: 
⎡                    -a⋅t                 ⎤
⎢                C₁⋅ℯ                     ⎥
⎢                                         ⎥
⎢     ⎛ a⋅t    b⋅t⎞  -a⋅t  -b⋅t           ⎥
⎢C₁⋅a⋅⎝ℯ    - ℯ   ⎠⋅ℯ    ⋅ℯ           -b⋅t⎥
⎢────────────────────────────── + C₂⋅ℯ    ⎥
⎣            a - b                        ⎦
```

The SymPy formula is slightly different and uses the Jordan form of the Matrix exponential implicitly absorbing the eigenvector matrix `inv(P)` into the constants:

```
In [63]: P, J = M.jordan_form()

In [64]: P*(J*t).exp() * sp.Matrix([C1, C2])
Out[64]: 
⎡    ⎛     b⎞  -a⋅t ⎤
⎢ C₁⋅⎜-1 + ─⎟⋅ℯ     ⎥
⎢    ⎝     a⎠       ⎥
⎢                   ⎥
⎢    -a⋅t       -b⋅t⎥
⎣C₁⋅ℯ     + C₂⋅ℯ    ⎦
```